# Import mysql dump in mysql workbench on Windows 10

Tags: mysql, windows-10

I'm trying to import and open a connection to mysql on my local computer. I have made an sql dump called frontend.sql

I did the following in mySQL workbench query:

`CREATE DATABASE frontend;`

`USE frontend;`

These queries were successful. Then I did

`SOURCE "C:\Users\John\Downloads\frontend.sql";`

Which gives the following error code:
`Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SOURCE C:\Users\John\Downloads\frontend.sql' at line 1`

How do I import the database?

Comment: In mysql  workbench why you not use menu  Flie> Import ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open a console where you can execute `mysql`

then hit this:

```
mysql -u username -p frontend < C:\Users\John\Downloads\frontend.sql
```